# How to access a file, which is 2 directories above on Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, directory, path, fs

I have this folder structure: 
[image]

Currently I am working on the **app.js** script  in the folder *scripts* and I am trying to read the **users.csv** file which lives inside the *replicate_to_mysql* folder. This is what I have tried so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path")

var user = fs.readFileSync(path.join('replicate_to_mysql', '../../..', 'user.csv')).toString();
```

However this throws the following error:

```
errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '..\\..\\generatedb.sql'
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve sth like this in node.js? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`let user = fs.readFileSync("../../replicate_to_mysql/user.csv", {encoding: "utf8});`

This is what I use when reading csv files in node.js when I know the directory I need to go. Outputs an array if you

`console.log(user);`

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require("fs");
const filename = "./replicate_to_mysql/user.csv";
const user = fs.readFileSync(filename);
console.log(data)
```