# How to access a file that's multiple dirs above (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, fs

I have a file `commandList.json` in my root folder, and `/commands/utility/stats.js` file, which attempts to access `commandList.json` file. However, this line:

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`../../commandList.json`);
```

Throws an error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..//..//commandList.json'
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861526/how-to-access-a-file-which-is-2-directories-above-on-nodejs), however, the first answer is wrong, and the second doesn't work. Could you please tell me how to access that file, or point to documentation that explains it well enough (I searched for docs regarding relative paths, both for Linux and node.js, but they weren't sufficient for me)?

Here are the attempted solutions I tried without success (every line throws the same error):

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`../../commandList.json`);
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`./../commandList.json`);
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`/commandList.json`);
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`..//..//commandList.json`);
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`../..//commandList.json`);
    //FYI the code is in "repo-name" repo, so maybe that's the root folder?
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`repo-name/commandList.json`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just when I was about to post the question, I have found a **working** solution:

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync(`././commandList.json`);
```

So, if you ever need to access a file multiple dirs above, you will need `./././ ...` structure.

I am posting this because I could not find the answer anywhere on the Internet and I hope this will help others find the solution much faster.

Comment: Helpful hint, the environment variable `__dirname` will point to your directory root folder. You can concatenate a path or use `path.join()` to access folders

Comment: @Elitezen the `__dirname` is a great tip, however I did not mention `path.join()` as I thought it's pretty self-explanatory (and knowledge is easily accessible [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-path-module)), I merely focused on the issue of moving back multiple directories at once.